# ORA-06413: Connection not open

Tags: asp.net, oracle

I am using Windows 7 64 bit OS. While making connection with oracle I got the error message.

> ORA-06413: Connection not open

I know based on the version this problem is occurring. But I don't know how to resolve this Error.

Comment: Is there a firewall that is blocking your communication with the database? Also check out [this MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/ab662d63-6385-4f73-b27f-d526048f601f/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having this same problem. There is couple of possible solutions for it:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_06413_connection_not_open.htm

But those didn't work for me.